# extract lines matching multiple conditions from variable column sized text file

Tags: bash, awk, substring

From a text file as example below, I'd like to print column 1 and 2 value if the line satisfy the condition of A=Jack and C=Bill.

```
1   123 A=Jack  C=Bill  D=Dad
1   423 A=Sue   B=Dad   C=Kirk  D=Pat  
1   483 A=Jack  B=Kirk  C=Bill  D=Bob
2   592 A=Sue   B=Bob   C=Bill
4   312 A=Jack  B=Kirk  C=Dad   D=Sue
```

So expected result is:

```
1   123
1   483
```

How do I accomplish this with either awk or grep?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please make an attempt at solving problems yourself before posting.

Comment: This is ridiculously simple. A quick look over either man page would provide enough information to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for word boundary:

```
awk '/A=Jack\>/&&/C=Bill\>/ { print $1, $2 }' file
```

`\>` creates a word boundary so that it doesn't match `Jackson` or `Billy` as [Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) suggested in the comments.

Comment: `\y` is gawk-specific too, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/A=Jack.* C=Bill.*/{print $1,$2}' file
```

EDIT: The above mentioned is doing uses regex to match any line that has the pattern  A=Jack and  C=Bill, once true, print columns 1 and 2

Comment: A little context as to how this answers the question will make it more useful to the community.

Comment: a little more description in the answer?

Comment: This showed up in the low quality queue. Presumably because it was a code only answer at the time